# save text file in upper case using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the program that convert all words to uppercase.

```
a = open("file.txt",encoding='UTF-8')

for b in a:
    c = b.rstrip()
    print(c.upper())
a.close()
```

this is my code
it prints uppercase text. But it can't save the file on 'file.txt'.
I want to convert all words to uppercase.

How can I solve it????

Comment: "it can't save the file on 'file.txt'" - have you _tried_ saving the uppercase text? The code in the question doesn't attempt to save it.

Comment: You need to either load all file to buffer and rewrite original file or write modified data to temporary file and replace original after.

Comment: yes. so I tried open the file mode by using 'w' and rewrite, but it doesn't work either..

Comment: @JiuLee, it could work if you will seek position back on length of each line, but it's not the way I would recommend you to proceed. Better to follow any of methods I've mentioned in previous coment.

Comment: @OlvinRoght okay. I'll try it. Actually I don't know many thing about python. so I don't know much about buffers. I'll study more about buffer, and I'll try the way you mentioned. I'm really thank you for your help

Comment: @JiuLee, there're few answers where you can find implementation of both methods.

Comment: @OlvinRoght okay I'll try all the answers and I will study how the codes working!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Here's how you can do it:** [provided that you are working with a small file]

Open the file in `read mode` store the uppercase text in a variable; then, open another file handler in `write mode` and write the content into it.

```
with open('file.txt' , 'r') as input:
    y = input.read().upper()
with open('file.txt', 'w') as out:
    out.write(y)
```

Comment: What if file size greater than available RAM?

Comment: "Must" is a bit strong. This will work (for small enough files), but it's not the *only* option.

Comment: thanks a lot. it works well!!  If you are okay I have little question. (I'm sorry I don't know a lot about programming so it might looks stupid) what happening if the file is big??

Answer (score 2):

First convert the txt into the string:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

And then revise the data to the uppercase:

```
data_revise = data.upper()
```

Finally revise the texts in the file:

```
fout = open('data/try.txt', 'w')
fout.write(data_revise)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. your anwer is easy to understand for me!  thankyou

Answer (score 2):

You can actually do this "in place" by reading and writing a character at a time.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    while (b := f.read(1)) != '':
        f.write(b.upper())
```

This is safe because you are processing the file one byte at a time (and writing one byte for every byte read) and not using `seek` to potentially overwrite a byte before it is read. The file-like object's underlying buffering and your system's disk cache means this isn't as inefficient as it looks.

(This does make one assumption: that the encoded length of `b` is always the same as `b.upper()`. I suspect that should always be true. If not, you should be able to read and write at least a line at a time, though not in place:

```
with open("input.txt") as inh, open("output.txt", "w") as outh:
    for line in inh:
        print(line.upper(), file=outh)
```

)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation !! thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write all changes to temporary file and replace original after all data processed. You can use either [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) or [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```py
with open(r"C:\original.txt") as inp_f, open(r"C:\temp.txt", "w+") as out_f:
    out_f.writelines(map(str.upper, inp_f))
```

```py
with open(r"C:\original.txt") as inp_f, open(r"C:\temp.txt", "w+") as out_f:
    out_f.writelines(s.upper() for s in inp_f)
```

To replace original file you can use [`shutil.move()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```py
import shutil
...
shutil.move(r"C:\temp.txt", r"C:\original.txt")
```

Comment: Oh! this is the way you said for me. thank you for your detailed explanation. I've never seen shutil. before, I think I'm gonna use it well at another programming. thanks a lot.